# Selenium Automation Fails to Generate Input Field

Tags: jquery, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am working on an automation test scenario where I will need to select an item from a dropdown and then a new item will be generated automatically.

[image: Screenshot]

Selecting "B" actually must trigger a text field after "B", but in automation it fails to generate the respective text field. If I do the scenario manually the text field will appear though.

I do not know the code behind the application, but the developer says that it utilizes jquery.js. The developer recommends to clear cache, and I had utilized a firefox profile that would not load cache, however the issue still occurs.

I wonder is there any workaround could be made to anticipate such issue related to Javascript and/or jquery?

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Update:

Here is my work so far:

```
    <select class="xui-selectinput xui-rule-when-select-attr xui-list" onmouseover="this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title">
    <option title="Select an attribute..." disabled="" selected=""></option>    
    <optgroup label="Interaction">
        <option title="Priority"value="workItem.priority"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<select class="xui-list xui-selectinput xui-rule-when-condition-operator" title="Select an operator...">

    <option disabled="" selected=""></option>
    <option title="Equals" value="Equals">
    </option>
</select>
            //To select "A"
            List <WebElement> element = null;
            element = wait.until.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementLocatedBy(By.xpath(//select[contains(@class,'xui-selectinput xui-rule-when-select-attr')]));
            Thread.sleep(stepInterval);
            Select clickTopic = new Select(element.get(0));
            clickTopic.selectByValue("workItem.priority");

            //To select "B"
            List<WebElement>  element = null;
            Thread.sleep(stepInterval);
            element = wait.until.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementLocatedBy(By.xpath(//select[contains(@class,'xui-rule-when-condition-operator')]));
            Select clickTopic = new Select(element.get(0));
            clickTopic.selectByValue("Equals");
```

The code able to select both from dropdown but again, the text field which is supposed to show just would not show up.

Comment: It would be great if you can post the HTML of it and what you have tried (code).

Comment: As can be seen from the HTML is that, before selecting the item from the drop down, mouse over on it using Actions class.

Comment: Hovering it does not make any difference, the text field still does not show up. Thanks